# Not able to connect with newly created RDS using CDK by pq client library

Tags: typescript, postgresql, aws-cdk

I have created RDS instance using CDK by `DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot`. Now I am trying to connect with newly created RDS instance using pg client in another stack, then I am getting below error.

*Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ${Token[TOKEN.439]}
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26)*

```
    import { Client } from 'pg';
    const client = new Client({
        user: username,
        host: props.rds_instance.rdst.dbInstanceEndpointAddress,
        database: 'postgres',
        password: 'xxxxxx',
        port: 5432,
    })
    client.connect()
```

Is there any other way to get host url?

Comment: You can't use the resources you deploy with CDK in the CDK app. You would either deploy a lambda that would connect to the DB, launch an EC2 instance, or an ECS service. You can pass the connection properties to all of these with environment variables or parameter store.

Comment: Is there any sample lambda function we can try it out. And how to trigger that lambda function after database creation ?

Comment: Sure, the code in the question would work as a sample lambda function once you put it in the handler and pass in the parameters via environment variables. Look into the lambda documentation first. I'd also start with invoking the lambda manually before you get comfortable.

Comment: I am able to get hostname in lambda but how to get master password of RDS instance as we are using rds.SnapshotCredentials.fromGeneratedSecret(username) while creating DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot?  How to pass stack while manually invoking lambda?

Comment: Pass the secret ARN to the lambda and use the AWS SDK to fetch its value from the lambda. Don't forget to grant read rights to the lambda.